# CLI singleton question

Tags: singleton, php

If two different PHP scripts are run via the CLI and they call an instance of a singleton, will they share the same instance?

This is how I'm creating the singleton

```
static $inst = null;
static $singleton = 0;
static $log;

public function __construct()
{
    if( self::$singleton == 0 )
    {
        throw new Exception('You must instantiate it using: $obj = MyClass::getInstance();');
    }
}

public static function getInstance()
{
    if( self::$inst == null )
    {
        self::$singleton = 1;
        self::$inst = new MyClass();
    }

    return self::$inst;
}
```

**Edit**: Now that I think about it, when I call include_once( 'myclass.php' ), both scripts include their own copies of the class. So there really is no reason they could share.

First, am I right in my assessment?

Second, out of curiosity, how could I share an instance of class between different scripts running independently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they will not. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493074/will-the-same-singleton-instance-be-available-after-php-script-command-line-call) why.